# Authorization in dropbox datastore

Tags: ios, dropbox, dropbox-api, datastore

I use datastore dropbox sdk in my ios app.

Yesterday my application worked, and today authorization error:

```
*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> Invalid object of type "NSNull" received.
2013-12-25 12:36:04.885 MCCoreData[11162:70b] [WARNING] DropboxSDK: error loading DBConnectController - Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x8cf5230 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=db-zsqvahc7cly3eop://1/connect?oauth_token=ylse13anatwjuyq9&oauth_token_secret=x9vg1ya77cvwadx&uid=3022092&state=47ce9e4d1c8f5128de8a25eedb5bb8fb, NSErrorFailingURLKey=db-zsqvahc7cly3eop://1/connect?oauth_token=ylse13anatwjuyq9&oauth_token_secret=x9vg1ya77cvwadx&uid=3022092&state=47ce9e4d1c8f5128de8a25eedb5bb8fb, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x8cf2280 "unsupported URL"}
```

I saw the same question, he was asked 2 months ago but no one answered

Comment: It would be great if you would link to the other question you saw. Perhaps there's more information there. My guess would be that you're somehow missing the URL scheme in your app settings. (See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/sdks/ios for instructions on how to set it up.)

Comment: I have had the same issue and have written some additional details on how to reproduce the bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126030/dropbox-ios-sdk-webkit-discarded-an-uncaught-exception