# Dropbox iOS SDK: WebKit Discarded an Uncaught Exception

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I am using the Dropbox iOS SDK (as of this writing, [Cocoapod version 1.3.9](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Dropbox-iOS-SDK)). I noticed a strange bug. Here are the steps to reproduce it.

**Connect to Dropbox, successfully sign in, and link to my account.**

URL logged to the console (tokens masked for security):

```
db-abcdef123://1/connect?oauth_token=xyz123&oauth_token_secret=lmno123&uid=10884&state=91D8CB70-1037-4A4C-8F7B-CB8970E5E0BC
```

App linked successfully!

**Sign out, then sign in with a *different* account...**

URL logged to the console again, similar to the previous one:

```
db-abcdef123://1/connect?oauth_token=def123&oauth_token_secret=jkl123&uid=95157647&state=DC716BF2-E033-4586-926C-5E733CEA1E3F
```

**Then comes the error:**

```
*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <Unsupported Signature Method> The signature method "(null)" is not currently support by MPOAuthConnection

[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error loading DBConnectController - Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x12848f00 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=db-abcdef123://1/connect?oauth_token=123abc&oauth_token_secret=xyz123&uid=95157647&state=DC716BF2-E033-4586-926C-5E733CEA1E3F, NSErrorFailingURLKey=db-abcdef123://1/connect?oauth_token=123abc&oauth_token_secret=xyz123&uid=95157647&state=DC716BF2-E033-4586-926C-5E733CEA1E3F, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x144c4c80 "unsupported URL"}
```

The Dropbox login screen remains in the `webView`, and clicking **Sign in** again causes the same error but then makes the app crash.

Any ideas?

---

*I'm using Xcode 5 and iOS 7*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue which will be fixed in the next release of the **iOS Dropbox app** (not the SDK).

**EDIT**: I misdiagnosed this based on the error message. The actual issue is likely that once you've initialized a `DBRestClient`, it continues to try to use the same user ID for authentication throughout its lifespan. If you unlink that user (even if you've added another user instead), it will fail to authenticate API calls because it no longer has credentials for that user.

The fix is to create a new `DBRestClient` when you switch to a new user.

This issue is present in the DBRoulette sample app. We're going to try to put in a fix for the next SDK release.

Comment: It may help to know that I'm getting this error in the iOS Simulator where I don't have the iOS Dropbox app. Perhaps the issue exists in your mobile web client as well.

Comment: I can reproduce this in the DBRoulette app. Certainly appears to be a bug in the Core SDK. Our engineering team is investigating.

Comment: See my edits. I think I know the issue now. (At least I know the issue in the DBRoulette app.) I hope this helps.

Comment: So doing `[[DBSession sharedSession] unlinkAll]` alone doesn't reset the `DBRestClient`?

Comment: That's correct. All that does is clear the credentials stored in the session. The DBRestClient will then try to get the credentials for a specific user from the session (which the session no longer has).

Comment: I'm getting this error again when using the iOS Dropbox Datastore API, and there is no `DBRestClient`. How do I fully reset the session with the Datastore API?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum Please create a new question and post some details.

Comment: September 2015 and this issue still exists.