# iOS Dropbox Datastore API: WebKit Exception + Unsupported URL

Tags: dropbox-api

*(Note, this seems [related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126030/dropbox-ios-sdk-webkit-discarded-an-uncaught-exception), but is with a different flavor of the Dropbox SDK.)*

Using the latest version of the Dropbox Datastore API on iOS, I am getting an exception after performing these steps:

1. Successfully connect my app to Dropbox
2. Disconnect my app from Dropbox.
3. Reconnect app to same, or another, Dropbox account.

Then this happens:

[image: Unknown Error Occurred: There was an error loading Dropbox. Please try again.]

The console in Xcode shows this:

```
*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:
decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: 
delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -[PilotPro.SettingsTableViewController 
dropboxWasLinked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc489cb94d0
```

And then this:

```
[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error loading DBConnectController - Error 
Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" 
UserInfo=0x7fc48c11bc50 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc48c4418c0 "unsupported URL",
 NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=db-***://1/connect?
oauth_token_secret=***&state=***&oauth_token=***&uid=***, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=db-***://1/connect?
oauth_token_secret=***&state=***&oauth_token=***&uid=***, 
NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}
```

I suspect I am not doing enough to disconnect Dropbox from my account, so it's conflicting with a Dropbox session somehow. Here's what I'm doing to disconnect:

```
//===::: Disable Dropbox :::===
DBAccountManager.sharedManager().linkedAccount.unlink()

// Shutdown and stop listening for changes to the datastores
DBDatastoreManager.sharedManager().shutDown()
DBDatastoreManager.sharedManager().removeObserver(self)

//Migrate back to local datastores
DBDatastoreManager.setSharedManager(DBDatastoreManager.localManagerForAccountManager(DBAccountManager.sharedManager()))
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the error message, it looks like your app isn't registered for the db-*** URL scheme, where *** is your app key. Can you confirm your app is registered for db-*** properly? (I.e., in your {AppName}-Info.plist file.) Are you using the latest version of the SDK? (Currently v3.1.2.) Are you able to reproduce this issue using a sample app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the errors given by Xcode were a bit of a red herring in this case. I was firing an `NSNotification` after Dropbox finished authenticating, and in doing so I was using this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "dropboxWasLinked:", name: "dropboxLinked", object: nil)
```

...but my `dropboxWasLinked` method wasn't set up to receive any arguments:

```
func dropboxWasLinked(){ ... }
```

So Xcode was firing an exception that messed up the authentication and made other things appear to be the cause, when in reality all I needed to do was remove the `:` from my `selector` in the `NSNotification` listener.

Ah, the joys of programming. :)